# What happens when I use `&` with a function in a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm debugging an oddity with a shell script and wondering whether I've misunderstood how Bash's "fork" (`&`) works, perhaps because I usually use it in single commands through a terminal, e.g.:

```
[~me]$ someExecutable &
```

Now, in a shell script:

```
foo() {
   echo "logic"
}

bar() {
   echo "idic"
}

baz() {
   echo "katra"
}

foo &
bar
baz
```

My intention is for the function `foo` to be invoked asynchronously, and then for the remainder of the script to continue executing in the original process context.

When I execute this example script I *do* get the expected output:

```
logic
idic
katra
```

<sup>(that is, only single apparent calls to `bar` and `baz`; I'm not at all bothered by the relative *order* of the three lines of output, which I understand may vary)</sup>

but I may be misunderstanding both the output and the script itself. If so, that would certainly explain the oddity I'm seeing in my real code, and save me from having to dig any further.

Is it possible that, in the child process, after the call to `foo`, the forked shell script will continue? Meaning that the remainder of my shell script will be executed *twice*?

**What really happens when I use `&` like this in a Bash script?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ampersand is only forking the call to foo() in your example.  It is not forking the entire script.  Only foo() runs in a separate thread, which exits when foo() finishes.  bar() and baz() continue to run in the same thread

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was after!

Comment: +1 for addressing the heart of the issue. Quibble: foo() runs in an (asynchronous) *subshell*, which is a separate *process*.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` in bash is not a fork.
It tells bash to launch the command in a subshell, and continue parsing for other commands (instead of waiting for that command to finish).

Therefore, as you expected, it runs 'foo' in the background, and continues to process the 'bar' and 'baz' command in the top level shell. No forking of the calling shell occurred, but 'foo' was run in the background.

So the output of "foo" could actually happen after bar or baz, depending on its content.. but as it uses "echo", which is a shell builtin, by the time the "foo" background process is setup, the "echo" is immediately available to it : therefore chances are good you see its output before the calling shell passes to the next command, which apparently is what happens in your case. (But YMMV! If "foo" was calling a heavy external command, it's likely its output would occur later on)

In the terminal, it's almost the same thing: you could  consider a terminal window with a shell prompt as a file script for that shell, that the login shell is reading "as you type it". The behavior is almost the same.

Comment: I'm not bothered about the order of the output, only that I get just three lines.

Comment: Same as if you typed it in a terminal. But I guess you already groked that :) It all stumbles down to : `&` is not a fork, ie it does not fork the calling shell (or rather shell+script). The shell spawns the command in a separate process and then handle it in the background, instead of waiting for it to finish before continuing. Ref http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html

Comment: Copy that. It means my instinct about it has been correct for all these years, but also that my original bug remains unexplained :(

Comment: We can maybe help with it? Care to explain a bit what bug it was, and extract lines around it? [try to pinpoint where it bugs, don't worry about values of variables at first]. Give us the output, why it's a bug, and the potential lines causing it

Comment: It's too entrenched within a system to describe directly, and I'm still not even entirely sure what the symptoms are, other than that something seems wrong for a number of reasons that simply have me suspicious and _may_ be causing a few more specific intermittent faults. I have been trying to construct a testcase for it all day; that I haven't finished yet is one of the reasons I didn't post an SO question about it ;) The other is that, having constructed a testcase, I should be able to fix it myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `&` character tells the shell to execute a command (or a group of commands) in the background.

The next commands are executed immediately.

There is no danger of executing the script twice, so it is different than C's `fork()` in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that the control operator `&` causes the command to be executed asynchronously in a subshell <sup>[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)</sup>, you could make use of [Coprocesses](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Coprocesses) to control the output.

Instead of invoking the function by saying:

```
foo &
```

say:

```
coproc fubar { foo; }
```

and then read the output by saying:

```
cat <&"${fubar[0]}"
```

This would also permit you to control the output (whether it needs to be emitted after or before other functions like `bar` or `baz`).

---

For example, the following:

```
foo() {
   echo "logic1"
   echo "logic2"
}

bar() {
   echo "idic"
}

baz() {
   echo "katra"
}

coproc fubar { foo; }
bar
baz
cat <&"${fubar[0]}"
```

would produce:

```
idic
katra
logic1
logic2
```

Comment: While the OP's issue is not directly addressed, it is good to know about coprocesses (bash 4+).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this command does run your function foo the background:

```
foo &
```

But by the time you enter `bar` and `baz` foo has already completed its run and printed its output on your terminal.

However if you run your functions like this then you will notice the difference:

```
foo & bar; baz
[1] 46453
idic
katra
logic
[1]+  Done                    foo
```

Here your process id might be different than mine but you can see that `logic` is printed in the end after outputs from other 2 functions.

Comment: I'm not bothered about the order of the output; it's that _only_ `foo` is run in the background, not forking the entire script.

Comment: No I wasn't stressing the order, I was merely pointing out that function `foo` was indeed called in background and `bar`, `baz` were called normally that's why order of output got changed.

Comment: I know that `foo` is run in the background but I wanted to make sure that the subprocess would _only_ run `foo`, and not continue with the rest of the script (resulting in the rest of the script running twice)